# ZF2 debugging custom view helper

Tags: debugging, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I a Zend Framework 2 custom view helper I use:

```
$uri = $this->view->vars()->mainMenu->findById('h');
```

The mainMenu property is a Zend\Navigation\Navigation object.

The result is that rendering of my view script stops at the point of executing the view helper without any error message. So for all practical purposes: the white screen of death.

In this view helper the line:

```
$uri = $this->view->vars()->mainMenu;
```

does work, so apparently the issue is with the findById() method.

But if I use the first line directly in my view script, I do get the expected result, a string containing the url of my home page: '/'.

My question is:

What is the issue with the findById() method in my view helper?

and/or (more importantly):

How can I debug this (and other, it is a recurring problem) issue in the view helper environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue by first addressing the second part of my question, by installing XDEBUG (on Zend Server CE) which finally gave some error output (calling method on non-object).

Where I was focusing on my layout view script, the same view helper also existed in my (final) view script where the navigation object was not available under the reference I used.

What works in both view and layout script is:

```
$uri = $this->view->layout()->getVariables()->mainNav->findById('h');
```

I found my solution here:

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/access-view-variables-in-another-view-model/

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that `findById()` doesn't exist. Check the [`Zend\Navigation\AbstractActionContainer`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/AbstractContainer.php) which the [`Zend\Navigation\Navigation`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/Navigation.php) extends.

The correct method (i guess) would be [`findBy()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/AbstractContainer.php#L321), [`findAllBy()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/AbstractContainer.php#L293) or [`findOneBy()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/AbstractContainer.php#L272)

```
$this->view->vars()->mainMenu->findOneBy('id', 'my-id-to-find');
```

Comment: these methods do not work either, findById is catched by __call and redirected to findOneBy. Anyway, findById works in my view script.

Comment: You're right, well it's adviced to not let the `__call()` handle things though. `Zend\Debug\Debug::dump(vars()->mainMenu)` it may be a navigation object, but is it the one you're expecting it to be?

Comment: yes, it is a nav object containing the page I am looking for (and the same code in my view script does find the page). I can dump the nav object but once I try the findOneBy method, there is no  error output at all.

Comment: Thx, you pointed me in the right direction: the issue was that I did 'exit' after dumping the nav object. The first time, using the helper in my layout script, it executed fine. Only the second time, in my view script, it could not find the object. But I did not get to that because of exit. And, by the way, I substituted FindById() by FindOneBy().